# HTML5 Cache Manifest caching request that is not define in manifest

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, local-storage, html5-appcache

I'm working on Application where I'm required to cache certain request for

So I was toiling with the HTML5 cache

Here my manifest file

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# 2d25a26de3a1148a2fa5e534325f84cca2184090174c6ba451451c54f71f52d6
assets/application.js
assets/application.css
assets/glyphicons/png/glyphicons_064_lightbulb.png
assets/jquery-mobile/ajax-loader.gif
assets/jquery-mobile/icons-18-white.png
application.manifest

NETWORK:
/project_show
/application.manifest
```

Now I have content in `/projects_show` page that look like this

```
<div data-role="header" class="header">
</div>

<div data-role="content" class="content">
</div>  

<div data-role="footer" class="footer" style="text-align:center">   
</div>  

<script type="text/javascript">
    <%= store_key %>
</script>

<script id="header" type="text/template">
    <h1>Listing of {{ carName   }}</h1>
</script>

<script id="content" type="text/template">
    <span>{{ pageName }}</span>
</script>

<script id="footer" type="text/template">
    <span> CopyRight &copy; {{ user }} </span> 
</script>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (window.navigator.onLine) {
                $.getJSON('/project/2.json',function(data) {

                   localStorage.setItem("acura",JSON.stringify(data));

                        var carTemplate = $('#header').html();
                        var pageTemplate = $('#content').html();
                        var footerTemplate = $("#footer").html();
                        $('div.header').html(Mustache.to_html(carTemplate, data));
                    $('div.content').html(Mustache.to_html(pageTemplate, data));
                $('div.footer').html(Mustache.to_html(footerTemplate,data));

                    })

      else {
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("acura"))
            var carTemplate = $('#header').html();
                var pageTemplate = $('#content').html();
                var footerTemplate = $("#footer").html();
            $('div.header').html(Mustache.to_html(carTemplate, data));
                $('div.content').html(Mustache.to_html(pageTemplate, data));
                $('div.footer').html(Mustache.to_html(footerTemplate,data));
      }             
    })
</script>
```

You Can See the idea over here is if the user is online fetch the `json` response from the server and if not then fetch the data from the `localStorage`

Unfortunately the above code is not working since Reason

a) Cache Manifest file is caching the `ajax` request as well

Now one can See I'm havent ask HTML cache manifest to cache the `json` request

i.e `/projects/2.json`

Can anyone tell me why is this so

The above code work fine if the `GET` request if modified to a `POST` request i.e `a POST request to`/projects/2.json`instead of GET`

But that is not what I'm looking for at any suggestion

FYI Manifest does follow the manifest file correctly as I also notice that my `/projects` getting cache even though not define in `manifest`

Comment: I'm too facing this problem did not knew if that can be solved via `post` thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `/project/2.json` to the `NETWORK` section of the manifest. Then requests for that URL should always be served from the server instead of from the appcache.

Regarding your `/projects` page getting cached: Do you bind that page to this appcache (by having a `manifest="..."` attribute in the `<html>` element of the page)? If you bind a page to an appcache, the page itself is always implicitly part of the appcache (as a so-called "master entry").

Comment: I thing that could be one options but I believe that it will not work in long run since question also has to tag of `ruby-on-rails` in rails `/projects/2.json` 2 can be replaced by any number like `/projects/999.json` or `/projects/1111.json` try to set an entry of each would be difficult and impossible to acheive

Comment: The entries in the `NETWORK` section use prefix matching, so if you add `/projects/` you would match all those json URLs.

Answer (score 0):

This was driving me nuts as well. What I found worked was to add to the NETWORK section of the manifest" "index.html#content". The way your are working it I think you need to also add "index.html#header" and "index.html#footer".

I think what is going on is index.html is cached. "Content" "Header" and "Footer" are part of that. Therefore the call to load those parts (or pages in my case) is trapped and the ajax call is not run because index.html is cached. By adding index.html#content to the NETWORK section it forces the call.